# Why and Where to call setLocale

Tags: java, android, sqlite, locale

I need to create a SQLite DB for my application. I'll need to store text in several European languages, so there will be plenty of accented characters and other weird marks. I'm extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Inspecting the .db file I noticed there's an extra table named `android_metadata`. There's a single column named `locale`, which is set to "en_US" by default in my simulator.

I've readed the SQLite section in the developer guide, and also the javadocs for `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase`, searched in SO and in Google, but nowhere I could find what is the correct place to set the locale to the DB, or if it is really neccesary. Guessing it should be done at DB creation, I tried calling `db.setLocale` in the helper's `onCreate` method, but I'm, getting this exception:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION failed setting locale
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1950)
```

This is how my method looks:

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   
        db.setLocale(new Locale("en","EN"));
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And here are my questions:

1. Do I really need to set the locale to the DB? I don't really need to get the queries sorted out of the box, as I can always sort the results myself later.
2. Where should I call `setLocale`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to set the locale only if you intend to use the `LOCALIZED` collation algorithm, which depends on the system locale,
2. As mentioned in your answer, call `setLocale()` on [`onConfigure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29).

Comment: Thanks. About #1, which char encoding is sqlite using? Most likely there would be no ordering difference for most ISO-8859 languages and the default (UTF-8?) ordering.

Comment: SQLite always uses UTF-8. It is recommended to use the `UNICODE` collation, which makes the DB independent of the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` docs the following method:

[void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29)

Copied from the method description:

> *Called when the database connection is being configured, to enable
>   features such as write-ahead logging or foreign key support. This
>   method is called before onCreate(SQLiteDatabase),
>   onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int), onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase, int,
>   int), or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) are called. It should not modify the
>   database except to configure the database connection as required. This
>   method should only call methods that configure the parameters of the
>   database connection, such as enableWriteAheadLogging()
>   setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean), setLocale(Locale),
>   setMaximumSize(long), or executing PRAGMA statements.*

This method gets called when the helper is creating the DB for the first time. I've checked the db file and the `android_metadata` now contains the correct locale. I've run some tests to store accented chars and they are written correctly to the db even without setting the proper locale.